# The difference between Connection.getWarnings() and Statement.getWarnings() in JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

I don't understand what the difference between in Connection.getWarning() and Statement.getWarnings() ?
Is the main difference that Connection.getWarning contains warnings for all statements and Statement .getWarnings contains warnings for single statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Connection.getWarnings` returns connection-level warnings, while `Statement.getWarnings` returns statement-level warnings. There is also `ResultSet.getWarnings`, which (surprise) returns result-set-level warnings. In other words, if a method called on a `Connection` produces a warning, it is added on the connection, for a method called on a `Statement` on the statement, and for a method of a `ResultSet` on the result set.

In general, warnings produced by a `Statement` should not be reported on the `Connection`, and warnings on a `ResultSet` should not be reported on the `Statement`. See for example [`Statement.getWarnings()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#getWarnings()) which says:

> Note: If you are processing a `ResultSet` object, any warnings
>   associated with reads on that `ResultSet` object will be chained on it
>   rather than on the `Statement` object that produced it.

and [`ResultSet.getWarnings()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getWarnings()) which says:

> Note: This warning chain only covers warnings caused by `ResultSet`
>   methods. Any warning caused by `Statement` methods (such as reading
>   OUT parameters) will be chained on the `Statement` object.

The JDBC specification is not very detailed on warnings, it only says ([JDBC 4.3](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index3.html), section 8.2 SQLWarning):

> When a method generates an `SQLWarning` object, the caller is not
>   informed that a data access warning has occurred. The method
>   `getWarnings` must be called on the appropriate object to retrieve the
>   `SQLWarning` object. However, the `DataTruncation` sub-class of
>   `SQLWarning` may be thrown in some circumstances, see Section 8.3
>   “DataTruncation” on page 8-46 for more details.
>
> If multiple data access warnings occur, they are chained to the first
>   one and can be retrieved by recursively calling the
>   `SQLWarning.getNextWarning` method. If there are no more warnings in
>   the chain, `getNextWarning` returns null.
>
> Subsequent `SQLWarning` objects continue to be added to the chain
>   until the next statement is executed or, in the case of a `ResultSet`
>   object, when the cursor is repositioned, at which point all
>   `SQLWarning` objects in the chain are removed.

and in section 8.3 DataTruncation:

> When data truncation occurs on a read from the data source, a
>   `SQLWarning` is reported.

and in section 15.1.1 *`ResultSet` Types*:

> If the driver does not support the type supplied to the methods
>   `createStatement`, `prepareStatement`, or `prepareCall`, it generates
>   an `SQLWarning` on the `Connection` object that is creating the
>   statement.

Similar text can be found in 15.1.2 *`ResultSet` Concurrency* and 15.1.3.1 *Determining `ResultSet` Holdability*.

Sometimes the JDBC API documentation explicitly mention warnings (eg [`Connection.setClientInfo​(String, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#setClientInfo(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) and [`ResultSet.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next())).

Although not specified by JDBC, drivers will commonly also report warnings during connect on the `Connection`.

Answer (score 1):

The Object type returned by the getWarnings method of Connection, Statement is not different. It is of type SQLWarning.

But depending on the context it has been called it differs.

1. Connection.getWarnings will retrieve database connection related warnings like database connection string doesn't have useSSL flag (warning logged in mysql).
2. Statement.getWarnings will retrieve sql statement related warnings like while executing statements inserting or deleting.